# Passing object to different windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to pass a C# object between win forms. At the moment, I have setup a basic project to learn how to do this which consists of two forms - form1 and form2 and a class called class1.cs which contains get and set methods to set a string variable with a value entered in form1. (Form 2 is supposed to get the value stored in the class1 object)

How can I get the string value from the object that was set in form1? Do I need to pass it as a parameter to form2?

Any comments/help will be appeciated!

Thanks,

EDIT: Here's the code I have at the moment: (form1.cs)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        form2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();

            class1.setStringValue(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, you could use a static class object, the above example would be ideal for this activity.

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
  public static string MyStringMessage {get;set;}
}
```

You don't need to instance the class, just call it

```
MyStaticClass.MyStringMessage = "Hello World";
Console.WriteLine (MyStaticClass.MyStringMessage);
```

If you want an instance of the object you can pass the class object that you create on Form1 into Form2 with the following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MyClass = class1;
        form2.Show();
    }
```

Then create a property on Form2 to accept the class object.

```
public Class1 MyClass {get;set;}
```

remember to make the Class1 object a global variable rather than create it within button 2 itself.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, Sres. Would you use a static class, for example, if you wanted to have a class used to store things that don't require many instances, like settings for an application? Whereas, a standard class could be used to create multiple instances if necessary, like user objects?

Comment: Exactly that, I use static classes in a number of places, to hold database Connection details, CurrentUser details.

Just be careful, especially if you get data that could change, you may end up with out of date information.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in Form1 you declare an instance of Class1 and then set the parameters as needed, then you pass it to Form2. You could for example have a constructor in Form2 and have a Class1 parameter in it. Assuming that Form1 creates Form2, otherwise you have to have some way for Form1 to find Form2 to pass the instance across.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have eddited my question and added the code for form1.cs - how can I pass the object instance to form2 since form2.show() is being called when a different button is clicked? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Rather than declaring `Form2 form2 = new ...` in the button1 event handler, just declare it as a member of the class. That way you'll be able to call `Form2.Show()` in the button1 event handler and you can also call something like  `From2.ShowNewValues(class1)` in the button2 handler.

Comment: Here you can find a sample of a class member: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson07.aspx

Comment: That makes sense, but would I have to have get and set methods in class1.cs and a get method in form2.cs to get data stored in the object instance of class1? Or would I call the get method in the form2 method ShowNewValues()?

Comment: Either way, but I'd probably do it that in the ShowNewValues method you'd call class1.GetSomething to get out the values and then use them right away. Though you might want to store copy of the whole of class1 instance as a member of Form2 if you're going to use the same values later for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have been working in ASP.Net the last couple years I have found myself working with Newtonsoft.Json a lot. Turns out to be great within WinForms too, and in this case seemed to simplify passing objects between forms... even complex ones are a breeze!

The implementation is like this:

```
// Set Object Property within Form
 public partial class FlashNotify : Form
 {
     public string Json { get; set; }
 }
```

On the form load event you can then grab your object:

```
 private void FlashNotify_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    // Deserialize from string back to object
    CommUserGroupMessage msg = new CommUserGroupMessage();
    msg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommUserGroupMessage>(Json);
 }
```

Lastly is passing the object to the form:

```
// Serialize the Object into a string to pass
 string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
 FlashNotify fn = new FlashNotify();
 fn.Json = json;
 fn.Show();
```

Granted the original selected answer is probably easier, however I like this approach <del>as it avoids the need to replicate the class within your form, which I think makes it easier to maintain</del> (**Correction:** Miss correctly read the static class in the example, I at first thought it was replicated within the form).

Comment: _"avoids the need to replicate the class within your form"_ - Huh?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Delegate** you can easily pass data to a form.

Technically, a **delegate** is a reference type used to encapsulate a method with a specific signature and return type

**Step 1**

Add a delegate signature to form1 as below:

```
public delegate void delPassDataToFrom(Object obj);
```

**Step 2**
In form1’s any button click event handler, instantiate form2 class and delegate. Assign a function in form2 to the delegate and call the delegate as below:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 frm = new Form2();
   delPassDataToFrom del = new delPassDataToFrom(frm.retrieveData);
   del(objectToPass);
   frm.Show();
}
```

**Step 3**

In form2, add a function to which the delegate should point to. This function will use the object passed:

```
public void retrieveData(Object objPassedFromParent)
{
  //use the objPassedFromParent object as needed
}
```