# How to pass list values from one class to other form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Actually I have 3 forms, and one class , class(ReadXMLToEcasWindow) in which i defined the list

```
public List<string> ack_line_path = new List<string>();
```

From **form 1 on button_click** , **form2**  will popup,
inside form2 i am adding values to List under the function

```
private void add_path_after_successful_load()
    {
        int rowcount = Ecas_config_gridview.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            XML_To_Ecas.ack_line_path.Add(Ecas_config_gridview.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        }

        this.Hide();
    }

//once  the values got added form2 will be hidden,  again **clicking  on form1 button**  , form3 under which i want to use these list values

private void btn_ECAS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ECAS_WINDOW_FORM F_Ecas= new ECAS_WINDOW_FORM(this);
    F_Ecas.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: pass it through constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957388/passing-object-to-different-windows-forms?rq=1 hope this will help you

Comment: i think the simplest way is to use Session

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple option by which you can send the values to another form in windows application.

1) Setting up properties:

```
ECAS_WINDOW_FORM F_Ecas= new ECAS_WINDOW_FORM(this);
F_Ecas.ack_line_path = this.ack_line_path;
F_Ecas.Show();
```

2) Send by method which answered previously:

```
ECAS_WINDOW_FORM F_Ecas= new ECAS_WINDOW_FORM(this);
F_Ecas.setYourList(list);
F_Ecas.Show();
```

3) Build a static class which will hold the values. You can access the values of the static class throughout any where in the application:

```
static class Holder
{
   public static List<string> ack_line_path = new List<string>();
}
```

Set the holder value

```
ECAS_WINDOW_FORM F_Ecas= new ECAS_WINDOW_FORM(this);
Holder.ack_line_path = this.ack_line_path;
F_Ecas.Show();
```

Then access the holder value anywhere inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

What about an easy way:

```
 ECAS_WINDOW_FORM F_Ecas= new ECAS_WINDOW_FORM(this);
 F_Ecas.setYourList(list);
 F_Ecas.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Ways to achieve this, simply the most obvious ways are:

A public method on Form 2 that you call it from the opener form after initializing form 2

Or, create another constructor for form 2 that accepts your list as input, and use this constructor when initializing form 2