# How to reference from an existing referenced object from different form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have in my opinion thoroughly looked for the answers in this website, but unfortunately I haven't found any or I just suck at looking at it.

I have 2 forms and 1 controller class and 1 model class or data class. In addition, `ControllerClass` has an array of the model class.

In `Form1` I did a reference to the controller like this:

```
ControllerClass control = new ControllerClass();
```

In `Form2` I want to reference from the `ControllerClass` I referred to in `Form1`.

Until now I have been doing something like:

```
ControllerClass control = new ControllerClass();
```

in `Form2` but this just makes a new copy of the `ControllerClass` which is not very helpful to me.

So how can I use the `ControllerClass` that I instantiated in `Form1` in `Form2`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957388/passing-object-to-different-windows-forms, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887820/how-do-you-pass-an-object-from-form1-to-form2-and-back-to-form1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp

Comment: Just pass the object as an parameter in the constructor of Form2 (`Form2 f2 = new Form2(control);`), or create a public property, which you fill with your object reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single object from a class, you could use a singleton.
Then ofc, you will always have the same object.

There are several ways how you can implement your control as a singleton

here some examples:
http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

For C# i prefer the nested version.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to pass the object to other forms through the constructor ([Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)), as others have suggested here, you can use a static object within the Form1.

For example, you could declare

```
public static ControllerClass control = new ControllerClass();
```

and then access the object like:

```
ControllerClass temp = Form1.control;
```

You can also make a second, static, class which will have the ControllerClass object (the class should be in the same namespace and not in the Form1 class), like so:

```
public static class ControllerStaticClass
{
    public static ControllerClass control = new ControllerClass();
}
```

Then you can access the ControllerClass object like:

```
ControllerClass temp = ControllerStaticClass.control;
```

Comment: It gave me an error saying Inconsistent Accessibility field type ControllerClass is less accessible than field form1.

Comment: Form1 class should be public (I have amended my answer).