# Why can't I set or change properties in other Forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms:

One login form:

[image: LoginForm]

One Create account form:

[image: Create Account Form]

and one software form where you get directed on a successful login. However that one is not relevant to my situation. Now, there is a class that looks like this:

[image: Classaccounts]

I use get; set; so I could get values from the account creator form.

This is the code of the Account Creator Form:

[image: code accountcreator]

So my question is, why does this not change the value of the properties in the Class Accounts.cs?

Comment: Post code, not pictures, please

Comment: To explain why we want code presented as text, [read this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (I've not voted on this question). You can amend your question via the edit link, and a formatting tool is available in the editor toolbar. The advice about posting text materials as text holds good for anywhere on the internet, at least where formatting tools are offered.

Comment: I'm sorry, First time. Will edit.

Comment: I figured I wouldn't need to post the code since it's more of a concept question.

Comment: "why does this not change the value of the properties in the Class Accounts.cs?" Your code *will* change the properties of the `accounts` instance held in the member variable `user`.  I'm guessing you have more than one instance. You seem confused about classes versus objects.

Comment: (If you genuinely don't need the code, you can just remove it, but readers often ask for it, so provide it if you're in doubt.)

Comment: @JohnWu It doesn't seem to change the properties, as I tried to login again using the login form I can't use the new values created by the createaccount form. if that makes sense.

Comment: is it just the email field that's not saved?

Comment: And when you say that you "login again" is it, as in, re-running the app?

Comment: @rickrvo no not re-running the program. The create account form closes when you store the value I use this.hide() for that.

Comment: this.hide() just hides the window :)

Comment: I think this is happening because you are just hiding your form. I suggest you to use 'System.Windows.Form.DialogResult.Ok'  instead of 'this.hide();'

Answer (score 0):

accounts user object is created within the form create account.

You need to pass the value to another form or use a static variable.

[Here explains how to create a static variable and how to pass object to another Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957524/2407557)

Answer (score 0):

The question was "why does this not change the value of the properties in the Class Accounts.cs?" . The posted code *will* change 2 of the 3 properties of the instance of that class. If you're not seeing that, you must be looking at a different *instance* of that class. Here's what you could do to get the information that was entered in the dialog from outside the dialog...

Rename the `accounts` class as `Account`, since each instance only represents one account, and it's common practise to capitalise class names.

On the account creator form, change the declaration of `user` to be a public property:

```
public Account user { get; } = new Account();
```

This makes it accessible from where you were using the form. So where you probably have some code like:

```
var form=new CreateAccountForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

You can now use `form.user` to access the contents of the instance of the Account class on that form.

However, you need to know whether they pressed the button or just closed the dialog. So set the `this.DialogResult=DialogResult.OK;` after the `string email=` line.

`string email=` should be replaced with `user.email=`.

`this.Hide();` should be `this.Close();`

Then the calling code can become:

```
var form=new CreateAccountForm();
if (form.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Do something with form.user here.
}
```

And of course any Form is disposable, so the declaration of `form` should be done in a `using` block.

Disclaimer: All of this was written away from my computer.