# Why does visual studio remove static from my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, static

I've manually set a label to a 'static', when I run the code it works fine but the next time I run the code it gives me a build error, this is because the 'static' got removed automatically.
I edited this in the formMain.Designer.cs file.

I looked on google and in Visual Studio itself but didn't find anything.

Here is a link to Paste-bin as the code would take to much space:
https://pastebin.com/LkPwrJhY
    `public static System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel lblSerialStatus;`

The label I changed is on the last line of code, 'lblSerialStatus', at line 180.
I'm changing this label because I want to change it from an other form.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What else is accessing formMain.lblSerialStatus which does not work when it's not static?

Comment: Questions with code from external sites are [not good for the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Comment: "Here is a link to Paste-bin as the code would take to much space" so only post the snippet that's required for us to help you

Comment: I did this to change the label from an other form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `formMain.Designer.cs` file is auto-generated. Meaning every time you change something in the visual designer this file gets re-generated over writing any manual changes done to the file
If you really want the label somewhere else you'll need to pass it as a parameter to some method. Also, static UI elements make no sense, because the UI will not always be there or be accessible

Comment: I get what you mean but how would I go about changing it from an other form then?
Also that you for this extremely fast answer.

Comment: How are you creating your second form?

Comment: This is the code I use.
    `private void serialToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formSerialSettings serialSettings = new formSerialSettings();

            serialSettings.TopMost = true;
            serialSettings.Show();
        }`

Comment: You could achieve this in a couple different ways. 1st creating a "setter" method on your `serialSettings` form to pass the label. 2nd create a Property on the `serialSettings` form and set it like that (basically equivalent to 1 but more C#y). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957524/9363973) answer might help out with code

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Designer.cs` file is not recommended. The file is automatically generated and it will be generated again whenever you change the corresponding forms file.

look before **`InitializeComponent()`** its also mentions in your `generated designer Code`

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

 /// <summary>
 /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
 /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
 /// </summary>
```

If you want then you can create another file which contains a `partial class` where you can put all such logic or function