# How to pass objects from one form to another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am working on winforms using c# where I have mutliple forms and one class. I want to use the same object of that class in all forms. How can I pass the objects from one class to another.
like in form2, I made an object user1 and then i wanna use the same user1 in form3. so for this I write a code which I have read on stake overflow but its not working.

```
private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            user1.login(textname.Text, textpassword.Text);
            if (user1.success==true)
            {
                Form f3 = new Form3();
                f3.SameUser = user2;
                f3.Show();
                
                this.Hide();
            }
```

and then on form3 I wrote:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public User SameUser { get; set; }
        // other function of form
     }
```

It is giving me this error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'User' is less accessible than property 'Form3.SameUser'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957388/passing-object-to-different-windows-forms  this is where I read

Comment: Please do not edit the question to completely change what you're asking, as this invalidates existing content on this page.  If you have a new question, you are encouraged to post a separate question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with your forms.  As the error states, the *type* `User` is less accessible (in this case "not public") than the form's `SameUser` property.

So consuming code can see the `SameUser` property, but might not be able to see what a `User` even is.

If you want that property to be `public` then the `User` class must also be `public`.

Comment: I made the user class public but now in form2 ` Form f3 = new Form3(); f3.SameUser = user2; ` here this error is occuring: `'Form' does not contain a definition for 'SameUser' and no accessible extension method 'SameUser' accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @MAHAJAVED: Because the type of the variable `f3` in that line of code is `Form`.  And `Form` indeed does not have a property called `SameUser`.  Make the type `Form3` instead.  (Or use the `var` keyword so you don't need to specify the same type twice on the same line of code.)